# How do I change the time zone for mail.log files?

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, timezone, debian-buster

I'm using Debian buster. I changed the time zone with timedatectl and restarted postfix and dovecot but log records in mail.log are still showing UTC time. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the log server that actually writes the log entries (in your case, probably `rsyslog`).

It was not the daemons *postfix* and *dovecot* that generate the timestamp, they just put their messages into syslog and `rsyslogd` proceded to format them with its configured time stamp format (*and currently selected timezone translation*).

General solution: To know which service exactly is writing to a file, it is often helpful to use *lsof*, e.g.:

```
lsof /var/log/file
lsof +D /some/directory/and/all/below/
```